# filter nearest row by date in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to filter by date on my pyspark dataframe.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
+------+---------+------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
|amount|cost_type|place2|             min_ts|             max_ts|        ds|
+------+---------+------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
|100000|  reorder|   1.0|2020-10-16 10:16:31|2020-11-21 18:50:27|2021-05-29|
|250000|overusage|   1.0|2020-11-21 18:48:02|2021-02-09 20:07:28|2021-05-29|
|100000|overusage|   1.0|2019-05-12 16:00:40|2020-11-21 18:44:04|2021-05-29|
|200000|  reorder|   1.0|2020-11-21 19:00:09|2021-05-29 23:56:25|2021-05-29|
+------+---------+------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
```

And I want to filter just one row for every possible ‍‍`cost_type` which has the nearest time to `ds`
for example for `ds = '2021-05-29'` my filter should select the second and fourth row. But for `ds = '2020-05-01'` should select the first and third row of my dataframe. If my ds was in the range of ‍‍‍`min_ts` and `max_ts` my filter should select that row for every cost type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible way is to assign row numbers based on some conditions:

1. Whether `ds` is between `min_ts` and `max_ts`.
2. If not, the smaller of the absolute date difference between `ds` and `min_ts`, or between `ds` and `max_ts`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy('cost_type').orderBy(
    F.col('ds').cast('timestamp').between(F.col('min_ts'), F.col('max_ts')).desc(), 
    F.least(F.abs(F.datediff('ds', 'max_ts')), F.abs(F.datediff('ds', 'min_ts')))
)

df2 = df.withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(w)).filter('rn = 1').drop('rn')
```